# Using .test domain for development in Ubuntu

Tags: laravel, apache, ubuntu, laravel-6

We are developing multiple subdomain based namespaces in our app so we want to have a local domain to be able to use a subdomain in our development.

I am doing the following configuration in the apache available sites but not able to serve the app in the browser.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias skreem.test
    DocumentRoot /home/admini/Desktop/skreemProduct/public/
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

have added the entry to the host file as well.

Comment: Have you updated the hosts file in your OS, or added this to a local DNS so your browser knows where to look for the site?

Comment: @rypskar yes have added to the hosts file

Comment: Take a look at Laravel Valet, configuration is very easy and setting up a local enviorment very easy as well. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/valet

Comment: @Collin thats for MAC, i am on ubuntu

Comment: @HarshaMV https://laravel-news.com/valet-for-ubuntu-linux, Valet is available for Ubuntu with a workaround. I have used a workaround to run in on windows. But in case you want a apache based solution, you might want to check this link. https://www.binarytides.com/create-localhost-sub-domains-apache-ubuntu/

Comment: @Collin in that it asked to install `php*-cli php*-common php*-curl php*-json php*-mbstring php*-mcrypt php*-opcache php*-readline php*-xml php*-zip` any idea how to install that?

Comment: Is this in sites-enabled?

Comment: you now this situation if probably super simple to solve so you need to check all the basic things like, apache status (`sudo systemctl status apache2`), make it run if it the case, make sure the folder is there (`/home/admini/Desktop/skreemProduct/public/`). For the sake of it, make a index.html only in there and try to display it in the browser. check the error.log and also the access log. after you do these things maybe you will have an idea of what is happening.

Comment: when the config is on `/etc/apache2/site-available` make sure you did a `ln -s /etc/apache2/site-available/CONFIG_NAME /etc/apache2/site-enabled` and after that you have made a `sudo service apache2 restart` or better `sudo a2ensite CONFIG_NAME`

Comment: or even better if you try to follow this url -> https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04